# Show that this function continuous in entire complex plane:

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that this function continuous in entire complex plane:

$$f(z)=\begin{cases} \frac{zRe(z)}{|z|} \;, &z\neq0\\{}\\0\; , &z=0\end{cases}$$
is continuous throughout the complex plane

I dont find how can i approach this.

Comment: Check the origin, and the rest is the ratio of continuous functions.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, only the origin  can give us problems, but then, using that $\;\frac z{|z|}\;$ is bounded, we get

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac z{|z|}\text{Re}\,z=0\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\lim_{x\to0}\text{ Re}\,z=0$$